# Cannot solve import javax.swing.* error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

When I create Java application builder and Main class in same package, and I imported javax swing as `import java.swing.*` then I have an error in main class.

**Main class**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SMS {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame(); //ok
        mf.setVisible(true);  //error
        mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //error
    }

}
```

I had an error last two lines as `The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type` and another one `The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type`.

And I already set JRE path as,

- Installed (and selected) JDK in Eclipse : `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`
- Selected JDK : `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries`
- Included "Java Builder" : `Project -> Properties -> Builders`

But I had an above error. Can I help me to fix this error to run my code...?

Comment: `MainFrame` is not declared within the `javax.swing` package. I'm surprised that you didn't get an error on the line `MainFrame mf = new MainFrame()` unless you imported more than just `javax.swing.*`,

Comment: right click on your project -> properties -> build path -> make sure your 'libraries' tab has the JDK (system library)

Comment: I think you're confusing Scala Swing with Java Swing.  You want `JFrame` I think.

Comment: JFrame mf = new JFrame();

Comment: Is `MainFrame` your own class, and does it extend JFrame?

Comment: Of cause I couldn't extends JFrame my own class... Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just change**

```
MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
```

**to**

```
JFrame mf = new JFrame();
```

**Explanation**

Unless mf is a class that extends `JFrame` you will not be able to invoke methods that are unique to it. Thus, in this case you can just simply change the object to a `JFrame` instead of `MainFrame`.

If `MainFrame` is your own internal class that you want to treat as a `JFrame`, add this to the class declaration:

```
extends JFrame
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly looking for `JFrame` rather than `MainFrame`?